# C++ handling common parameters for several executables

Tags: c++

Hi I have a C++ project with several executable and lots of code.
Each executable is equivalent to a single brick in my algorithms chain but common parameters are needed by different executables. I would like to store these params but how to do this properly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities for you to consider:

- Environment variables
- An XML file
- Using a database

It's hard to provide more specific guidance without knowing more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MS Visual Studio : Select the projects which need the common parameters in the Solution explorer and choose properties (alt-enter) goto the run-parameters and give values and save.